# SQL FIFO Logic in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, fifo

I am sorry before if that title doesn't represent my problem here.

I have table 1 with multiple items.

TABLE 1

```
|No|Item|Quantity X|    
|1 |A   |20        |
|2 |A   |21        |
|3 |A   |10        |
|4 |B   |3         |
|5 |B   |4         |
...
```

My custom FIFO function result for item A:

```
|No|Name     |Quantity Y|           
|1 |Document1|2         |   
|2 |Document2|20        |   
|3 |Document3|5         |   
|4 |Document4|1         |   
|5 |Document5|22        |
```

My custom FIFO function result for item B:

```
|No|Name       |Quantity Y|         
|1 |Document100|2         | 
|2 |Document101|2         | 
|3 |Document102|4         |
```

The expected result:

TABLE 2

```
Item|Quantity X|Name       |Quantity Y|
A   |20        |Document1  |2         |
A   |20        |Document2  |18        |
A   |21        |Document2  |2         |
A   |21        |Document3  |5         |
A   |21        |Document4  |1         |
A   |21        |Document5  |13        |
A   |10        |Document5  |10        |
B   |3         |Document101|2         |
B   |3         |Document102|1         |
B   |4         |Document102|1         |
B   |4         |Document103|3         |
```

I have using SQL Server 2008. How to achieve this with SQL?

Comment: I don't understand the relation between each table..

Comment: what does your FIFO function look like ? and from where is this Document data coming ?

Comment: You are probably wanting to use [`cross apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) - but I cannot see how your data joins up.

Comment: take a look at this article [t-sql-window-function-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-problem](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/t-sql-window-function-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-problem/)

Comment: As I understand: we take first row from `TABLE1` No=1 qty=20 - from `item A` first document 2, second 20, for first we take 2 from qty, for second 18 left, and the 2 for second we take from `TABLE1` No=2 qty=21 and so on.

Comment: @gofr1 that's it, this how i want join my data. Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes, there are :) Please, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got one weird answer here :) Please, sit down and take a look.

```
--I use cte's to show you a sample of how it wiil work
--Here comes table with incoming docs
;WITH table1 as (
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'A',  20),(2, 'A',  21),(3, 'A',  10),(4, 'B',  3),(5, 'B',  4)
)AS t([No],Item,[Quantity X])
--Here comes table with outgoing item A
), itemA AS (
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES        
(1, 'Document1',2),(2, 'Document2',20),(3, 'Document3',5),(4, 'Document4',1),(5, 'Document5',22)
)AS t([No], Name, [Quantity Y])   
--Here we fraction each quantity for documents in 1, 
--so if quantity is 20 there will be 20 rows with 1 
), recT1 AS (
    SELECT [No], Item, [Quantity X], 1 as [level], 1 as Qty
    FROM table1
    WHERE Item = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [No], Item, [Quantity X], [level] +1,1
    FROM recT1 
    WHERE [level] < [Quantity X]
--same to items
), recA AS (
    SELECT [No], [Quantity Y], 1 as [level], 1 as Qty
    FROM itemA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [No], [Quantity Y], [level] +1,1
    FROM recA 
    WHERE [level] < [Quantity Y]
--here we add ROW_NUMBER not to lost order
), finalT1 as (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [No], [Level]) as rn
    from recT1 
), finalA as (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [No], [Level]) as rn
    FROM recA
)
--final query!
SELECT  t.Item,
        t.[Quantity X],
        ia.Name,
        CASE WHEN a.[level] > t.[level] THEN t.[level] ELSE a.[level] END as [Quantity Y]
FROM finalT1 t
INNER JOIN finalA a
    ON t.rn = a.rn
LEFT JOIN itemA ia
    ON ia.[No] = a.[No]
WHERE a.[level] = a.[Quantity Y] or t.[level] = t.[Quantity X]
```

Output:

```
Item    Quantity X  Name        Quantity Y
A       20          Document1   2
A       20          Document2   18
A       21          Document2   2
A       21          Document3   5
A       21          Document4   1
A       21          Document5   13
A       10          Document5   9
```

For `B`

```
Item    Quantity X  Name        Quantity Y
B       3           Document100 2
B       3           Document101 1
B       4           Document101 1
B       4           Document102 3
```

Comment: It works fine! Big thanks. I've only added clause `OPTION (maxrecursion 0)`

Comment: My pleasure! There was not much data - so I forgot about `OPTION (maxrecursion 0)` :(. If it helps be free to upvote/accept my answer!